# Proof of Gaussian coefficients identity

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I want to show the identity $\bigl[\!\begin{smallmatrix} n \\ k \end{smallmatrix}\!\bigr]_q=\bigl[\!\begin{smallmatrix} n-1 \\ k-1 \end{smallmatrix}\!\bigr]_q+q^k\bigl[\!\begin{smallmatrix} n-1 \\ k \end{smallmatrix}\!\bigr]_q$ for $0<k<n$ and the steps I followed are
\begin{eqnarray*}
\bigl[\!\begin{smallmatrix} n \\ k \end{smallmatrix}\!\bigr]_q-\bigl[\!\begin{smallmatrix} n-1 \\ k-1 \end{smallmatrix}\!\bigr]_q &=&\frac{(q^{n}-1)(q^{n-1}-1)\cdots(q^{n-k+1}-1)}{(q^{k}-1)(q^{k-1}-1)\cdots(q-1)}-\bigl[\!\begin{smallmatrix} n-1 \\ k-1 \end{smallmatrix}\!\bigr]_q\\
&=&\left(\frac{q^{n}-1}{q^{k}-1}-1\right)\bigl[\!\begin{smallmatrix} n-1 \\ k-1 \end{smallmatrix}\!\bigr]_q\\
&=&q^k\frac{q^{n-k}-1}{q^{k}-1}\bigl[\!\begin{smallmatrix} n-1 \\ k-1 \end{smallmatrix}\!\bigr]_q\\
&=&q^k\frac{(q^{n-k}-1)(q^{n-1}-1)\cdots(q^{n-k+1}-1)}{(q^{k}-1)(q^{k-1}-1)\cdots(q-1)}\\
&=&q^k\bigl[\!\begin{smallmatrix} n-1 \\ k \end{smallmatrix}\!\bigr]_q
\end{eqnarray*}

Assuming that the rest of the derivation is correct, the only part I was not able to show is the last equation (which should hold) i.e.
$$\frac{(q^{n-k}-1)(q^{n-1}-1)\cdots(q^{n-k+1}-1)}{(q^{k}-1)(q^{k-1}-1)\cdots(q-1)}=\bigl[\!\begin{smallmatrix} n-1 \\ k \end{smallmatrix}\!\bigr]_q$$
even though I am not sure whether this is the correct way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your numerator:

$$ \color{Red}{(q^{n-k}-1)}(q^{n-1}-1)\cdots(q^{n-k+1}-1)$$

Move the first term to the end of the product.